# Laravel: How submit checked checkbox values without form action?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I will display messages in this way using loop:

```
<tr @if($message->seen == 0) class="unread"
    @elseif($message->seen == 1) class=""
    @endif
    >
    <td class="inbox-small-cells">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-default inline-block">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox012" name="checked[]"  value="{{encrypt($message->id)}}"/>
            <label for="checkbox012"></label>
        </div>
        <a href="{{route('inbox').'/'.encrypt($message->id)}}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete inline-block font-16"></i></a>
    </td>
    <td class="view-message  dont-show">
        <a href="{{ route('message'). '/' .encrypt($message->id) }}">
            {{$message->subject}}
        </a>
        @if($message->seen == 0)
            <span class="label label-warning pull-right">new</span>
        @endif
    </td>
    <td class="view-message ">{{$message->messageSender->email}}</td>
    <td class="view-message  text-right">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-attachment inline-block mr-15 font-16"></i>
        <span  class="time-chat-history inline-block">{{ $message->created_at->format('H:i') }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here I have checkboxs with name `checked[]` and values with `id` message. And I have this links in the top of view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Mark as Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Spam</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can be sended checked checkbox values using links `<a href="{{ route('name') }}">Delete</a>`

Or how send correctly? Or I must use form?

Comment: JS `onchange=""` event ??

Comment: I not used js in my template

Answer (score 0):

you can submit it with the javascript, just use element `<a>` and route the href on the controller method.

Comment: I must send all checked elements with one button

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call to submit the data user have clicked .

I maynot have best solution , but this is what i have

Assign id for dropdown list .

and write onclick event for that id and assign different function for each 
example :

```
<li id="read"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Mark as Read</a></li>
```

similarly give id to all the list in dropdown and call this function for all

```
<script>

   $('#read').click(function(){
       var val = [];
       $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
       val[i] = $(this).val();
     });

       //now you have all the selected message's id in val array which is encrypted 

      //now you can make ajax call for passing this value to laravel controller  and give route to the url : in the ajax 

//like :

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: {info:val},
       url: url_need_to_be_given_here ,
      success: function(msg){
         console.log(msg);
       }
       });          
     });

</script>
```

This will pass all the selected message id to controller to which the url direct to and you can decrypt that and make query and perform operation what is needed  ..

Will be happy if i am helpful to you